# Is it possible to overload abs() in C++?

Tags: c++, overloading

I'm writing a library to handle 2D matrix algebra, using a template for the type of data inside the matrix, in order to have the most freedom possible and handle matrices of, basically, whatever type of data I want.

I was wondering if there was some way to overload the `abs()`  function, in order to write the matrix' determinant as `abs(M);` , or if I had to use another name for that. My only concern is that the matrix' determinant is related to its absolute value (as the standard notation suggests), so in my mind it makes sense to overload the absolute value function to return the determinant.

I already tried to make it a class method, and call it with `m.abs();` , and obviously that worked just fine... but I wanted the function to be outside of the class, and get the matrix as an argument, just like the `int abs(int n);`  function works. So, I tried to just overload the function, and that gave me some problems because the `abs(n);` function expects some integer or long value as an argument, surely not an user-defined matrix. I also tried to make it a friend method of the class, but it doesn't seem to help. Looking forward to your suggestions.

Comment: There is no "abs" function to overload, unless you're talking about `std::abs`, but you wouldn't be considering writing your own functions in the `std` namespace... right!??

Comment: "So, I tried to just overload the function, and that gave me some problems...."  we have no way to know what "problems" you are talking about unless you show us the code and the error message. Please read about [mcve]

Comment: @paddy `abs`, like other C functions, is allowed to exist in global namespace, it's implementation-defined IIRC.

Comment: Most people would expect the abs() function to return a positive value. However, the general matrix determinant can be positive or negative. On the other hand, I think most users would appreciate what det(M) was supposed to do.

Comment: "so in my mind it makes sense to overload the absolute value function to return the determinant.". Rather than changing the meaing of names because "it makes sense" use the right names. A function that calculates the determinant can be called `determinant`. Don't overload for the sake of overloading. When the different overloads do different things it does more harm than good

Comment: A small addition to @paddy. You should not overload `std::abs` or write a function in namespace std, either in global. Instead, you should create a new namespace like `Matrix`, then write a function like `abs` or `det` in it

Comment: The determinant of a matrix is not related to the notion of absolute value. (The "determinant bars" are not the same symbol as the "absolute value bars".) See e.g. [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value) for some explanation of the notation.

Comment: I agree that overloading `abs` might be confusing, but the question can still be answered (assuming that OP shows us their code and error message). Also note that both absolute values and matrix determinants are denoted by the notation `|...|`, so the idea isn't crazy.

Comment: At least do it properly then using operator| and let `|M|` evaluate to the determinant or std::abs depending on the type of M.

Comment: @rubenvb I'm genuinely curious how you want to implement `det = |M|;` in C++. Last I've checked, `|` is a binary operator but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @Homer512 Closest I can get is this: https://godbolt.org/z/8bb7rr84P
Mayhaps there's a way to abuse a zero-width space instead of `_` but I'm not sure such a hidden character actually qualifies for an [identifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers). I never said it was pretty, my comment was meant more in a tongue-in-cheeck way, but you got me thinking.
Apparently, a zero width space can't be used here: https://godbolt.org/z/jq58EEW18

Comment: Correction: GCC accepts it: https://godbolt.org/z/9zr8arvnc

Comment: Please understand I do not recommend using that in real code, ever.

Comment: @rubenvb that's … very cursed but I applaud your tenacity in proving your point

Comment: and even without preprocessor defines!

Answer (score 9):

C++ has a feature called [argument-dependent lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) that is designed for cases like this where you want overloads between free-standing functions. The typical application for this is overloading `std::swap` but you can use it here, too.

```cpp
#include <cmath>
// using std::abs
#include <iostream>

namespace my_ns {

class Matrix
{};

float abs(const Matrix&)
{
    std::cout << "Calling abs(Matrix)\n";
    return 0.f;
}

} /* namespace my_ns */

int main()
{
    my_ns::Matrix mat;
    std::cout << abs(mat) << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
Calling abs(Matrix)
0
```

The key point is that you don't specify the namespace when calling `abs`. If you call `std::abs(mat)` it will fail. However, it still works if you write `using std::abs`. That is useful for templates so that you can use `std::abs` for standard types but also your own `abs` in your own namespace.

```cpp
template<class T>
auto call_abs(const T& value)
{
    using std::abs;
    return abs(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to overload abs() in C++

Yes, it is, though not recommended. The reasons are as follows:

1. `abs` is defined in namespace `std`, which is part of the standard lib. You  should write your own functions in another namespace of your own, such as `Matrix`
2. `abs` is usually used to calculate the absolute value of a number, such a name will be confusing.

If you still want to do so, you can do this very easily:

```cpp
#include <cmath>

struct Matrix {};

int abs(const Matrix &m) { return 0; }

int main() {
  Matrix m;
  int det = abs(m);
}
```

---

Here are some possible ways to implement your `abs` (though I think `det` may be a better name):

```
// Matrix.h
namespace matrix {
class Matrix { /**/ };

int det(const Matrix&);
} // namespace matrix
```

Or:

```
class Matrix {
    static int det(const Matrix&);
};
```

Comment: should be `int abs(const Matrix &m)`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Correction completed

Comment: Overloading functions in namespace `std` like you have described gives undefined behaviour.    There are a few specific circumstances where it is allowed but the case you have given is not one of them.   Have a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std  for relevant information.

Comment: @Peter Thanks a lot, I was completely unaware of such restrictions before this. Can I understand that as we should not add definitions or declarations in namespace `std` except they include templates?

Comment: Roughly speaking, it is possible to specialise templates that are in the standard library but not possible to simply add new templated functions or classes to `std`, or to (as you did) overload functions that are in the standard library.