# Eigen can't match unary function

Tags: c++, eigen3

I am encountering a compile issue with Eigen 3.4.0.

Specifically, I have a template function for calculating the area of a triangle:

```
template <typename T, int D>
auto TriangleArea(const Eigen::Matrix<T, D, 1>& p0, const Eigen::Matrix<T, D, 1>& p1, const Eigen::Matrix<T, D, 1>& p2) {
    const auto e01 = p1 - p0;
    const auto e02 = p2 - p0;
    return Eigen::sqrt(e01.dot(e01) * e02.dot(e02) - e01.dot(e02) * e01.dot(e02)) / T{2};
}
```

This code results in an error:

> no matching function for call to
> ‘sqrt(Eigen::ScalarBinaryOpTraits<double, double,
> Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double> >::ReturnType)’

How do I fix this issue with sqrt not being found?

Comment: Please post a complete error message with notes, that explain what `ReturnType` is. And post a [mcve] with all #include and `main()` that calls `TriangleArea()`

Comment: If the code results in the same error message without the template, you've removed some complexity from the problem. If it does something else, you've learned more about the problem.

Comment: Ahhh, I see. That is rather frustrating that Eigen::sqrt doesn't have overloads for arithmetic types considering you could end up in a similar situation where you have a Matrix that could be a row vector times a column vector.

Comment: Well, not quiet. First, you call `dot`, which is only valid for vectors so you always get a scalar. If you wrote `e01.transpose() * e01 + …`, which would be valid for matrices and vectors, you instead get a proper expression that *could* work with `Eigen::sqrt`. However, that's a matrix expression and `Eigen::sqrt` only works with array expressions since a [matrix sqrt](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/group__MatrixFunctions__Module.html) is something different. You can write `Eigen::sqrt((e01.transpose() * e01 + …).array())` and [it will compile](https://godbolt.org/z/TTsaKrfjh).

Comment: Overall, this type of namespace confusion is supposed to be solved via argument-dependent lookup, see for example my answer for [Is it possible to overload abs() in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76857772/is-it-possible-to-overload-abs-in-c/76857986#76857986). That's how you're supposed to use `Eigen::sqrt` to begin with. Applied to your problem: https://godbolt.org/z/ad7MoE577

Comment: BTW: When responding, please write @Homer512 (or whoever you respond to). Otherwise we don't get a notification unless we explicitly check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the template is that `dot` results in a scalar.  `Eigen::sqrt` is defined for `ArrayBase< Derived >` as seen [here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/namespaceEigen.html#af4f536e8ea56702e63088efb3706d1f0).

`dot` may be replaced by transpose multiplication which will instead return an `Eigen` object.

```
template <typename T, int D>
auto TriangleArea(const Eigen::Matrix<T, D, 1>& p0, const Eigen::Matrix<T, D, 1>& p1, const Eigen::Matrix<T, D, 1>& p2) {
    const auto e01 = p1 - p0;
    const auto e02 = p2 - p0;
    return Eigen::sqrt(
        (e01.transpose() * e01 * e02.transpose() * e02
        - e01.transpose() * e02 * e01.transpose() * e02).array()) / T{2};
}
```

Alternatively, since the input to `sqrt` is a scalar in this case, the standard `sqrt` may be used.

```
#include <cmath>
...    
template <typename T, int D>
auto TriangleArea(const Eigen::Matrix<T, D, 1>& p0, const Eigen::Matrix<T, D, 1>& p1, const Eigen::Matrix<T, D, 1>& p2) {
    const auto e01 = p1 - p0;
    const auto e02 = p2 - p0;
    return std::sqrt(e01.dot(e01) * e02.dot(e02) - e01.dot(e02) * e01.dot(e02)) / T{ 2 };
}
```