# Custom scalar type with Eigen : Inverting compiles for 4x4 matrices, but not for 5x5 matrices

Tags: c++, eigen, finite-field

So, I'm trying to use Eigen to do some computations with matrices with a custom scalar type (that being elements of a finite field). I have the following code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <cassert>

namespace Eigen
{
    template <short N>
    struct int_mod {
        int_mod() : n(0) {}
        int_mod(int n_) : n((n_+N)%N) {}
        
        int_mod operator-(){ return N-n; }
        int_mod operator+(int_mod i) const { return (n+i.n)%N; }
        int_mod operator*(int_mod i) const { return (n*i.n)%N; }
        int_mod operator-(int_mod i) const { return (n-i.n+N)%N; }
        int_mod operator/(int_mod i) const { 
            int t = 0;
            int newt = n;
            int r = N;
            int newr = i.n;
            
            while(newr != 0) {
                int q = r/newr;
                int temp = newt;
                newt = t-q*temp;
                t = temp;
                temp = newr;
                newr = r-q*temp;
                r = temp;
            }
            
            if(r>1) { throw std::runtime_error("Not invertible"); }
            if(t<0) t = t+N;
            return t;
        }
        
        void operator=(const int_mod& other){ n = other.n; }
        void operator=(const int& other){ n = other; }
        void operator+=(const int_mod& other){ int_mod res = (*this)+other; this->n = res.n; }
        void operator-=(const int_mod& other){ int_mod res = (*this)-other; this->n = res.n; }
        void operator*=(const int_mod& other){ int_mod res = (*this)*other; this->n = res.n; }
        void operator/=(const int_mod& other){ int_mod res = (*this)/other; this->n = res.n; }
        
        bool operator==(int_mod i) const { return n == i.n; }
        
        static constexpr short mod() { return N; }
        
        short n;
    };

    template<short N>
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, int_mod<N> i) { os << i.n; return os; }

    template<short T> struct NumTraits<int_mod<T>> : NumTraits<int>
    {
      typedef int_mod<T> Real;
      typedef int_mod<T> NonInteger;
      typedef int_mod<T> Nested;
     
      enum {
        IsComplex = 0,
        IsInteger = 0,
        IsSigned = 1,
        RequireInitialization = 1,
        ReadCost = 1,
        AddCost = 3,
        MulCost = 3
      };
    };
}

typedef Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 5, 5> MatrixMod;

int main()
{
    MatrixMod m = MatrixMod::Identity();
    
    MatrixMod mi = m.inverse();
    
    std::cout << mi << std::endl;
}
```

However, I get the following error message :

```
In file included from EigenTest.cpp:2:
In file included from /usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/Dense:1:
In file included from /usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core:171:
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/MathFunctions.h:1511:10: error: call to function 'abs' that is neither visible in the template definition nor found by argument-dependent lookup
  return abs(x);
         ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/functors/UnaryFunctors.h:44:111: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Eigen::numext::abs<Eigen::int_mod<3>>' requested here
  EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE const result_type operator() (const Scalar& a) const { return numext::abs(a); }
                                                                                                              ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/CoreEvaluators.h:583:12: note: in instantiation of member function 'Eigen::internal::scalar_abs_op<Eigen::int_mod<3>>::operator()' requested here
    return m_d.func()(m_d.argImpl.coeff(row, col));
           ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/CoreEvaluators.h:1123:22: note: in instantiation of member function 'Eigen::internal::unary_evaluator<Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_abs_op<Eigen::int_mod<3>>, const Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 5, 5>>>::coeff' requested here
    return m_argImpl.coeff(m_startRow.value() + row, m_startCol.value() + col);
                     ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Redux.h:381:18: note: in instantiation of member function 'Eigen::internal::unary_evaluator<Eigen::Block<const Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_abs_op<Eigen::int_mod<3>>, const Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 5, 5>>, 5, 1, true>>::coeff' requested here
  { return Base::coeff(IsRowMajor ? outer : inner, IsRowMajor ? inner : outer); }
                 ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Redux.h:128:17: note: in instantiation of member function 'Eigen::internal::redux_evaluator<Eigen::Block<const Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_abs_op<Eigen::int_mod<3>>, const Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 5, 5>>, 5, 1, true>>::coeffByOuterInner' requested here
    return eval.coeffByOuterInner(outer, inner);
                ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Redux.h:110:75: note: (skipping 19 contexts in backtrace; use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to see all)
    return func(redux_novec_unroller<Func, Evaluator, Start, HalfLength>::run(eval,func),
                                                                          ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/AssignEvaluator.h:890:46: note: in instantiation of member function 'Eigen::internal::Assignment<Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 5, 5>, Eigen::Inverse<Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 5, 5>>, Eigen::internal::assign_op<Eigen::int_mod<3>, Eigen::int_mod<3>>>::run' requested here
  Assignment<ActualDstTypeCleaned,Src,Func>::run(actualDst, src, func);
                                             ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:797:17: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Eigen::internal::call_assignment_no_alias<Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 5, 5>, Eigen::Inverse<Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 5, 5>>, Eigen::internal::assign_op<Eigen::int_mod<3>, Eigen::int_mod<3>>>' requested here
      internal::call_assignment_no_alias(this->derived(), other.derived(), internal::assign_op<Scalar,typename OtherDerived::Scalar>());
                ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:594:7: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 5, 5>>::_set_noalias<Eigen::Inverse<Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 5, 5>>>' requested here
      _set_noalias(other);
      ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:423:9: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 5, 5>>::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Inverse<Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 5, 5>>>' requested here
      : Base(other.derived())
        ^
EigenTest.cpp:82:17: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 5, 5>::Matrix<Eigen::Inverse<Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 5, 5>>>' requested here
        MatrixMod mi = m.inverse();
                       ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/MathFunctions.h:1509:1: note: 'abs' should be declared prior to the call site or in namespace 'Eigen'
abs(const T &x) {
^
In file included from EigenTest.cpp:1:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/iostream:43:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/ios:221:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:18:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/mutex:191:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/shared_ptr.h:30:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/uninitialized_algorithms.h:13:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__algorithm/copy.h:14:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__algorithm/min.h:12:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__algorithm/comp.h:47:71: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('const Eigen::int_mod<3>' and 'const Eigen::int_mod<3>')
    bool operator()(const _T1& __x, const _T1& __y) const {return __x < __y;}
                                                                  ~~~ ^ ~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__algorithm/max.h:33:12: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__less<Eigen::int_mod<3>>::operator()' requested here
    return __comp(__a, __b) ? __b : __a;
           ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__algorithm/max.h:42:19: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::max<Eigen::int_mod<3>, std::__less<Eigen::int_mod<3>>>' requested here
    return _VSTD::max(__a, __b, __less<_Tp>());
                  ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/MathFunctions.h:1094:10: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::max<Eigen::int_mod<3>>' requested here
  return max EIGEN_NOT_A_MACRO (x,y);
         ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/GenericPacketMath.h:524:57: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Eigen::numext::maxi<Eigen::int_mod<3>>' requested here
pmax(const Packet& a, const Packet& b) { return numext::maxi(a, b); }
                                                        ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/GenericPacketMath.h:530:90: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Eigen::internal::pmax<Eigen::int_mod<3>>' requested here
  return pminmax_impl<NaNPropagation>::run(a, b, EIGEN_BINARY_OP_NAN_PROPAGATION(Packet,(pmax<Packet>)));
                                                                                         ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/functors/BinaryFunctors.h:176:22: note: (skipping 11 contexts in backtrace; use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to see all)
    return internal::pmax<NaNPropagation>(a,b);
                     ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/AssignEvaluator.h:890:46: note: in instantiation of member function 'Eigen::internal::Assignment<Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 5, 5>, Eigen::Inverse<Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 5, 5>>, Eigen::internal::assign_op<Eigen::int_mod<3>, Eigen::int_mod<3>>>::run' requested here
  Assignment<ActualDstTypeCleaned,Src,Func>::run(actualDst, src, func);
                                             ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:797:17: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Eigen::internal::call_assignment_no_alias<Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 5, 5>, Eigen::Inverse<Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 5, 5>>, Eigen::internal::assign_op<Eigen::int_mod<3>, Eigen::int_mod<3>>>' requested here
      internal::call_assignment_no_alias(this->derived(), other.derived(), internal::assign_op<Scalar,typename OtherDerived::Scalar>());
                ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:594:7: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 5, 5>>::_set_noalias<Eigen::Inverse<Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 5, 5>>>' requested here
      _set_noalias(other);
      ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:423:9: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 5, 5>>::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Inverse<Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 5, 5>>>' requested here
      : Base(other.derived())
        ^
EigenTest.cpp:82:17: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 5, 5>::Matrix<Eigen::Inverse<Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 5, 5>>>' requested here
        MatrixMod mi = m.inverse();
                       ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__utility/pair.h:465:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'pair' against 'int_mod'
operator< (const pair<_T1,_T2>& __x, const pair<_T1,_T2>& __y)
^
In file included from EigenTest.cpp:2:
In file included from /usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/Dense:2:
In file included from /usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/LU:29:
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/LU/PartialPivLU.h:382:28: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('Score' (aka 'int_mod<3i16>') and 'Score')
      if(biggest_in_corner != Score(0))
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/LU/PartialPivLU.h:439:14: note: in instantiation of member function 'Eigen::internal::partial_lu_impl<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 0, int, 5>::unblocked_lu' requested here
      return unblocked_lu(lu, row_transpositions, nb_transpositions);
             ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/LU/PartialPivLU.h:519:7: note: in instantiation of member function 'Eigen::internal::partial_lu_impl<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 0, int, 5>::blocked_lu' requested here
    ::blocked_lu(lu.rows(), lu.cols(), &lu.coeffRef(0,0), lu.outerStride(), &row_transpositions.coeffRef(0), nb_transpositions);
      ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/LU/PartialPivLU.h:543:13: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Eigen::internal::partial_lu_inplace<Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 5, 5>, Eigen::Transpositions<5, 5>>' requested here
  internal::partial_lu_inplace(m_lu, m_rowsTranspositions, nb_transpositions);
            ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/LU/PartialPivLU.h:133:7: note: in instantiation of member function 'Eigen::PartialPivLU<Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 5, 5>>::compute' requested here
      compute();
      ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/LU/PartialPivLU.h:315:3: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Eigen::PartialPivLU<Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 5, 5>>::compute<Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 5, 5>>' requested here
  compute(matrix.derived());
  ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/LU/PartialPivLU.h:604:10: note: (skipping 3 contexts in backtrace; use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to see all)
  return PartialPivLU<PlainObject>(eval());
         ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/AssignEvaluator.h:890:46: note: in instantiation of member function 'Eigen::internal::Assignment<Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 5, 5>, Eigen::Inverse<Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 5, 5>>, Eigen::internal::assign_op<Eigen::int_mod<3>, Eigen::int_mod<3>>>::run' requested here
  Assignment<ActualDstTypeCleaned,Src,Func>::run(actualDst, src, func);
                                             ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:797:17: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Eigen::internal::call_assignment_no_alias<Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 5, 5>, Eigen::Inverse<Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 5, 5>>, Eigen::internal::assign_op<Eigen::int_mod<3>, Eigen::int_mod<3>>>' requested here
      internal::call_assignment_no_alias(this->derived(), other.derived(), internal::assign_op<Scalar,typename OtherDerived::Scalar>());
                ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:594:7: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 5, 5>>::_set_noalias<Eigen::Inverse<Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 5, 5>>>' requested here
      _set_noalias(other);
      ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:423:9: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 5, 5>>::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Inverse<Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 5, 5>>>' requested here
      : Base(other.derived())
        ^
EigenTest.cpp:82:17: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 5, 5>::Matrix<Eigen::Inverse<Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 5, 5>>>' requested here
        MatrixMod mi = m.inverse();
                       ^
In file included from EigenTest.cpp:2:
In file included from /usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/Dense:1:
In file included from /usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core:318:
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Visitor.h:227:14: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('const Scalar' (aka 'const Eigen::int_mod<3>') and 'Scalar' (aka 'Eigen::int_mod<3>'))
    if(value > this->res)
       ~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Visitor.h:59:7: note: in instantiation of member function 'Eigen::internal::max_coeff_visitor<Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_score_coeff_op<Eigen::int_mod<3>>, const Eigen::Block<Eigen::Block<Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 5, 5>>, 5, 1, true>, -1, 1>>, 0>::operator()' requested here
      visitor(mat.coeff(i, 0), i, 0);
      ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Visitor.h:129:101: note: in instantiation of member function 'Eigen::internal::visitor_impl<Eigen::internal::max_coeff_visitor<Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_score_coeff_op<Eigen::int_mod<3>>, const Eigen::Block<Eigen::Block<Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 5, 5>>, 5, 1, true>, -1, 1>>, 0>, Eigen::internal::visitor_evaluator<Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_score_coeff_op<Eigen::int_mod<3>>, const Eigen::Block<Eigen::Block<Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 5, 5>>, 5, 1, true>, -1, 1>>>, -1>::run' requested here
  return internal::visitor_impl<Visitor, ThisEvaluator, unroll ? int(SizeAtCompileTime) : Dynamic>::run(thisEval, visitor);
                                                                                                    ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Visitor.h:374:9: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_score_coeff_op<Eigen::int_mod<3>>, const Eigen::Block<Eigen::Block<Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 5, 5>>, 5, 1, true>, -1, 1>>>::visit<Eigen::internal::max_coeff_visitor<Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_score_coeff_op<Eigen::int_mod<3>>, const Eigen::Block<Eigen::Block<Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 5, 5>>, 5, 1, true>, -1, 1>>, 0>>' requested here
  this->visit(maxVisitor);
        ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:501:14: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_score_coeff_op<Eigen::int_mod<3>>, const Eigen::Block<Eigen::Block<Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 5, 5>>, 5, 1, true>, -1, 1>>>::maxCoeff<0, long>' requested here
      return maxCoeff<PropagateFast>(index);
             ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/LU/PartialPivLU.h:377:55: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_score_coeff_op<Eigen::int_mod<3>>, const Eigen::Block<Eigen::Block<Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 5, 5>>, 5, 1, true>, -1, 1>>>::maxCoeff<long>' requested here
        = lu.col(k).tail(rows-k).unaryExpr(Scoring()).maxCoeff(&row_of_biggest_in_col);
                                                      ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/LU/PartialPivLU.h:439:14: note: (skipping 8 contexts in backtrace; use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to see all)
      return unblocked_lu(lu, row_transpositions, nb_transpositions);
             ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/AssignEvaluator.h:890:46: note: in instantiation of member function 'Eigen::internal::Assignment<Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 5, 5>, Eigen::Inverse<Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 5, 5>>, Eigen::internal::assign_op<Eigen::int_mod<3>, Eigen::int_mod<3>>>::run' requested here
  Assignment<ActualDstTypeCleaned,Src,Func>::run(actualDst, src, func);
                                             ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:797:17: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Eigen::internal::call_assignment_no_alias<Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 5, 5>, Eigen::Inverse<Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 5, 5>>, Eigen::internal::assign_op<Eigen::int_mod<3>, Eigen::int_mod<3>>>' requested here
      internal::call_assignment_no_alias(this->derived(), other.derived(), internal::assign_op<Scalar,typename OtherDerived::Scalar>());
                ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:594:7: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 5, 5>>::_set_noalias<Eigen::Inverse<Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 5, 5>>>' requested here
      _set_noalias(other);
      ^
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:423:9: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 5, 5>>::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Inverse<Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 5, 5>>>' requested here
      : Base(other.derived())
        ^
EigenTest.cpp:82:17: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 5, 5>::Matrix<Eigen::Inverse<Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::int_mod<3>, 5, 5>>>' requested here
        MatrixMod mi = m.inverse();
                       ^
4 errors generated.
```

if I change the line

```
typedef Eigen::Matrix<int_mod<3>, 5, 5> MatrixMod;
```

to

```
typedef Eigen::Matrix<int_mod<3>, 4, 4> MatrixMod;
```

the program compiles just fine and even does exactly what I need it to.

I have no idea what's going on, so if someone could offer some insight, that would be amazing. I'm new to learning Eigen so any advice would be helpful.

Thanks!

I'm trying to perform a calculation using a custom scalar type in Eigen. But the program will not compile for 5x5 matrices and larger. The error code I get is not helpful to me since it is saying abs and < are not defined, which they wouldn't be with the scalars I am working with.

I would like for my program to work, but I would also like to understand what is going on.

Thank you!

Comment: I doubt you are allowed to define user types in the Eigen namespace.

Comment: I notice "`return abs(x);`"  in your error messages. Shouldn't that be `return std::abs(x);`?

Comment: Eigen is not well suited for doing abstract algebra over arbitrary fields. It is geared towards numeric stability. This only makes sense when you do real number calculations with finite precision.

Comment: You can try to define trivial comparison operators and abs for your type to appease Eigen (just operate on the underlying representation). They should allow your code to compile and perhaps even work correctly, although they won't make sense otherwise.

Comment: See here (custom scoring): https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCustomizing_CustomScalar.html The reason it works up to `n=4` is that Eigen uses a direct approach without pivoting.

Comment: @JesperJuhl no, not writing the namespace is correct. It's argument-dependent lookup, which facilitates building custom types and overloading free-standing functions like `std::abs`, see for example [Is it possible to overload abs() in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76857772/is-it-possible-to-overload-abs-in-c/76857986#76857986). If OP can define it mathematically, they can simply write `friend int_mod abs(int_mod i) { return … }` into their class definition and the compiler will pick it up

Comment: @chtz I suspected they were using a different algorithm for 4x4. Thanks for the reference!

Comment: @Homer512 I added the lines
`friend int_mod abs(int_mod x) { return x; }
bool operator!=(int_mod i) const { return n != i.n; }
bool operator>(int_mod i) const { return false; }
bool operator<(int_mod i) const { return false; }
`
into the class definition and it works now. Thank you so much!

Comment: Overloading `abs` and `operator<` that way may make it compile and work often, but it might not work in some cases (as in declare matrices non-invertable, which in fact are). Really, read the bottom half of the link I sent! (Or at least make sure that `0` is smaller than every other number)

Comment: @chtz Haha. Yeah, I just ran into that problem. I was able to figure out that it was the comparison operators that were giving it grief. Thanks so much!